# Issue with code using Interface Options Addon in World of Warcraft

Tags: xml, lua, add-on, world-of-warcraft

I am writing a UI to a pre-existing addon. Or, more specifically, adding configuration options and trying to take advantage of the Interface Options Addons (IOA) panel. I've been referencing wowwiki, specifically the [page that talks about using that panel](http://www.wowwiki.com/Using_the_Interface_Options_Addons_panel), but more generally a bunch of pages.

I'm running into a problem that I'm sure is just a result of my inexperience writing addons (I've written a few, but it's a learning experience every time). The basic concept is:

- Create the main panel - using XML
- Create sub-items for things that should be visible on the main panel (is, global options) - using XML
- Create a sub-panel for each child item (configuration category) - using Lua (the number and names of the sub-panels is dynamic)
- Create sub-items for each sub-panel - using Lua

The things that work are:

- The main panel shows up in the IOA panel
- The sub panels show up in the IOA panel, as sub-items of the main panel
- The textures I put on the sub panels show up on them

The problems I'm having are:

- If I create the sub-panels as children of the main panel, they show up on top of the main panel
- If I create the sub-panels are children of the UIParent, they show up on the main screen (visible when the IOA window isn't open
- Nothing I create in the XML file as a child Frame of the main panel shows up on it

The code I have so far (clipped for brevity) is at the bottom of the message. Any help/suggestions would be more than appreciated. I know there's a lot in the code section, but I wanted to be as clear as I could about what I was doing.

Note that I did post about this on the official Warcraft UI forum, but was unable to get any help there.

**embeds.xml**

```
...snip...
<Frame name="MyAddonFrame" parent="UIParent" hidden="false">
  <Scripts>
    <OnLoad>
      self:RegisterEvent("UNIT_TARGET");
      self:RegisterEvent("PLAYER_ENTERING_WORLD");
      MyAddon_OnLoad(self);
    </OnLoad>
    <OnEvent function="MyAddon_OnEvent" />
    </Scripts>

    <Frames>
      <Frame parent="MyAddonFrame" inherits="UIDropDownMenuTemplate">
        <Frames>
          <Button name="MyAddon_MacroSelectDropdownButton">
            <Anchors>
              <Anchor point="CENTER"/>
            </Anchors>

            <Scripts>
              <OnLoad>
                UIDropDownMenu_Initialize(this,
                MyAddon_MacroSelectDropdown_OnLoad);
              </OnLoad>
              <OnClick>
                MyAddon_MacroSelectDropdownButton_OnClick();
              </OnClick>
            </Scripts>
          </Button>
          <MessageFrame>
            <Anchors>
              <Anchor point="CENTER"/>
            </Anchors>
          <FontString text="Message Frame"/>
        </MessageFrame>
      </Frames>
    </Frame>
  </Frames>
</Frame>
...snip...
```

**Lua Code**

```
...snip...
function MyAddon_OnLoad(panel)
    MyAddon_CreateOptionsPanel(panel);
    MyAddon_ConsoleMessage("Loaded MyAddon: " .. tostring(panel));
end

function MyAddon_CreateOptionsPanel(panel)
    panel.name = "MyAddon " .. GetAddOnMetadata("MyAddon", "Version");  -- Set the name for the Category for the Panel
    panel.okay = function (self) MyAddonFrame_Close(); end;                 -- When the player clicks okay, run this function.
    panel.cancel = function (self)  MyAddonFrame_CancelOrLoad();  end;  -- When the player clicks cancel, run this function.
    InterfaceOptions_AddCategory(panel);                                    -- Add the panel to the Interface Options

    for name,text in pairs(ConfigData) do
        MyAddon_CreateMacroPanel(name, panel, panel.name);
    end
end

function MyAddon_CreateMacroPanel(macroName, parent, parentName)
    MyAddon_ConsoleMessage("Added macro option pane: " .. macroName);
    panel = CreateFrame( "Frame", "MyAddon_MacroPanel_" .. macroName, parent);
    panel.name = macroName;
    panel.parent = parentName;
    InterfaceOptions_AddCategory(panel);

    -- create a backdrop so we can see that the panel is created
    panel:SetFrameStrata("BACKGROUND");
    panel:SetWidth(128); -- Set these to whatever height/width is needed 
    panel:SetHeight(64); -- for your Texture

    local t = panel:CreateTexture(nil,"BACKGROUND");
    t:SetTexture("Interface\\Glues\\CharacterCreate\\UI-CharacterCreate-Factions.blp");
    t:SetAllPoints(panel);
    panel.texture = t;

    panel:SetPoint("CENTER",0,0);
end



-- MyAddon_MacroSelectDropdown
function MyAddon_MacroSelectDropdown_OnLoad()
    info            = {};
    info.text       = "Auto";
    info.value      = "Auto";
    -- FunctionCalledWhenOptionIsClicked 
    info.func       = function (self) MyAddon_SetMacroAuto(); end;
    UIDropDownMenu_AddButton(info);
    for index,macro in pairs(ConfigData) do
        info.text       = name;
        info.value      = name;
        -- FunctionCalledWhenOptionIsClicked 
        info.func       = function (self) MyAddon_SetMacroByName(name); end;
        UIDropDownMenu_AddButton(info);
    end
    -- can also be done as function() FunctionCalledWhenOptionIsClicked() end;
end
...snip...
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, frames that are childeren are drawn on top of their parents by default.  This is a fundemental tenant.

I think the disconnect here is partly in the assumtion that you are needing to add all elements as children of your main frame.  This isnt so.

For two independant "panels", i.e. Frames, you can have:

```
<frame>...</frame>
<frame>...</frame>
```

If the first is your "main frame", or the one that you intend to recive your addons main events, like ADDON_LOADED, the second can be someting else, but its still yours.  Well both really arn't "yours" actually, they are in a global shared scope shared by all addons.

So if you want visible elements that follow a particular frame, both in position and visibility they should be its children.  Else you should create another frame.  If you make a parent hidden then its children will be hidden. If you move a parent, its children move, via the fact they have relative positions to the parent.

These are the default behaviours, but unless you really need to do something tricky, like a frame that truely morphs, its much easier to follow the default behaviour and create seperate frames.

---

```
<Frame name="MyAddonFrame" parent="UIParent" hidden="false">
  <Scripts>
    <OnLoad>
      self:RegisterEvent("UNIT_TARGET");
      self:RegisterEvent("PLAYER_ENTERING_WORLD");
      MyAddon_OnLoad(self);
    </OnLoad>
    <OnEvent function="MyAddon_OnEvent" />
    </Scripts>

    <Frames>
      <Frame parent="MyAddonFrame" inherits="UIDropDownMenuTemplate">
```

You dont need to set the parents as you did above, but if you intend to reference that frame from lua code outside of an event directly in that frame, you should give it a name:

```
    <Frames>
      <Frame name="$parentDropDownMenu" inherits="UIDropDownMenuTemplate">
```

---

If this is in "embeds.xml", techincally that file is meant for a set of includes for libs that are embedded in the addon, and not for managing frames, but of course WoW has no idea so it would work.  The code should be in someting more like MyAddon.xml, MyAddon.lua

---

Mostly you need to make frames that are the right size and register them to show as part of the options panel, which is sort of the nutshell explanation of it.

Let me know whats left that doesnt make sense or work.